# Swift 4 - set value to webKit using evaluateJavaScript

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, xcode10

I am trying to set a value from my project in Swift to a website using `evaluateJavaScript` but when I set the value he set success but he only placeholder not Really Value. How can I fix it?

See this image to understand what I mean:

[image]

```
@objc func handleStart() {
     webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value='\(textTagOne.text!)'", completionHandler: nil)
}
```

//This is HTML //

Comment: Could you show the HTML you are trying to manipulate with this JavaScript as well?

Comment: <input class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" id="f1f056ae1da129" aria-describedby="slfErrorAlert" aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" value="">

Comment: @Terje I added now

Comment: I don't think this is a Swift problem - I think you'll have the same problem running the JavaScript in a regular browser instead. How is your placeholder displayed on your input field?